# Как убрать время в таблице с данными от бд? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

Такая проблема: Мне надо выводить таблицу с данными с базы данных. Все получается и прекрасно, но дело в том что дата выводится почему-то со временем, хотя тип данных в бд ток DATE. Может кто подсказать в чем проблема? (Данные приведенные в таблицы придуманы мной)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
        string sql = $"select concat(patient.family, ' ', patient.imy, ' ', patient.otchestvo) as fio, " +
            $"patient.pole as pole, patient.data_birth as happybirth from patient;";
        public StartupApplication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Connection.FillGrid(sql, membersDataGrid);
            
    }
```

Разметка: `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата рождения" IsReadOnly="True"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding happybirth}" />`

Класс Connection:

```
public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();
public static void FillGrid(string sql, DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=YourDoctor;User Id=postgres;Password=Devilmaycry135790;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmdSel = new NpgsqlCommand(sql,connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `{Binding happybirth, StringFormat=d}`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!